# Multipanel radar animation

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, metpy

I am currently having trouble getting the Multi-panel radar animation to plot. I am using juypter notebook and on the last cell I get this error.

```
anim = ArtistAnimation(fig, new_artists, interval=100)
anim
```

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Does anyone have any advice? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that with the animation, the Python kernel is sending too much data back to the notebook client (running in your web browser). What you need to do is run the notebook with a command line argument to increase the data limit (as mentioned in the error message). So run the notebook as:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=100000000
```

And I would expect things to work. The default I believe is 10000000.